# Cannot update DataStudio resource connection to use service account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, looker-studio, service-accounts

I have a DataStudio dashboard which contains a dataset resource connection to a BigQuery table which is currently authenticated using an individual user's account.

I want to change that to use a service account.

In order to do that, I followed [this guide](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/10835295?visit_id=637939104097159626-501963927&p=sa-err-missing-role&rd=1#error-missing-role&zippy=%2Cin-this-article), which means I have:

1. Created a service account
2. Added the **BigQuery Job User** role to the service account
3. Added the **Service Account Token Creator** role to the service account
4. Added the **BigQuery Data Viewer** role to the service account (associated to the correct BigQuery table)
5. Ensured that my account is added as a **Service Account User** on the service account

On the DataStudio dashboard, I then navigate to:

*Resource > Manage Added Data Sources > Select the specific data source > Click on the blade with the current user account being used to authenticate*.

When I try to insert the service account details in the window, I see the error message below.

[image: Adding service account to resource]

I've followed the link (which leads back to the original guide). The link says I need to add the **Service Account Token Creator** to the service account, which I've confirm through the following:

[image]

Now I'm stumped! What could be the reason why I cannot authenticate the connection using the service account?

Comment: I found that it took me a while and multiple refreshes to get it to work. I also initially had to add the agent as a data viewer. After that I removed it and it still worked.

Comment: Thanks @Avi I'll try adding the data viewer role as well and give it another try.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.

The problem was that the **Service Account Token Creator** role was assigned to the service *account* and not the service *agent*.

[This link](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/10835295?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article) describes the process of setting up a service account for authenticating Data Studio data sources. Although it's got all the info there, the devil is in the detail in **Step 2: Allow the Looker Studio service agent to access your service account**.